# First app help, with fetching audio

Tags: ios

Im using Xcode and toying around trying to make my first program. In my program i want it to have a place to insert a URL, then go to the URL fetch the audio from the data on the web page and then add that audio to a playlist in the app.

Comment: what have you tried to do so far?  also, what kind of app are you trying to make?  an iOS app or a Macintosh app?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I guess i just dont know where to really start, im trying to do this on my own and teach myself on the way and am hoping im not trying something that cant be done. I am trying to make an iOS app. so far i have just gotten the buttons set up, and all pretty much the design of the app done, now having trouble with the toughest part.

Comment: What does "fetch the audio" mean? How would you do this yourself, without the app doing it?

Comment: @matt sorry im doing a crummy job explaining things. I want to make part of the program be a box that you paste a url of say, a video and the app takes the audio downloads it to a playlist located in the app

Comment: Why? Downloading takes time. It takes space. Why not just put the URL into the playlist? Then when the user wants to play it, then you start streaming the audio.

Comment: @matt see this is why this place rocks haha , good idea I don't know why I didn't think  of that, even then I don't know how to begin that but it will take some research I suppose

Comment: @LoganKorn you can start with some tutorials on your favourite topic (like audio streaming) and then build up knowledge and start off. The iOS developer community is probably the largest in the world and with lots of helpful people like Matt Neuburg (whom you have been conversing with). Did you know that he is a famous iOS book writer? http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032465.do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with all of the other excellent iOS resources available on the web, Apple's own developer site has plenty of good documentation and guides.  Have a look at [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW4) for some information on playing back an audio/video stream from a URL